# VBO not working with OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to render a simple triangle with vbos (not indexed!). But for some reason it doesn't work. Nothing shows up on my display. This is code for OpenGL ES 2.0 on the raspberry pi.
Here is part of my code:

```
void RenderGL::drawGL() {
    glViewport(0, 0, 480, 320);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboHandle);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    shaderProgram.bindGL();

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    shaderProgram.unbindGL();
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

and

```
void RenderGL::initGL(std::string shaderPath) {
    quadVertices.push_back(-0.5f);
    quadVertices.push_back(-0.5f);
    quadVertices.push_back(0.0f);
    quadVertices.push_back(1.0f);

    quadVertices.push_back(-0.5f);
    quadVertices.push_back(0.5f);
    quadVertices.push_back(0.0f);
    quadVertices.push_back(1.0f);

    quadVertices.push_back(0.5f);
    quadVertices.push_back(0.5f);
    quadVertices.push_back(0.0f);
    quadVertices.push_back(1.0f);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vboHandle);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quadVertices.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), 
        &quadVertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    shaderProgram.initGL(shaderPath);
}
```

My shaders (which compile and link without error):

```
attribute vec4 vert_position;
void main() {
    gl_Position = vert_position;
}
```

and

```
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0, 0, 1.0);
}
```

And my shader setup code:

```
void ShaderProgramGL::compileShader() {
    vertShaderHandle = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    const char* vertS = vertSrc.c_str();
    glShaderSource(vertShaderHandle, 1, &vertS, 0);
    glCompileShader(vertShaderHandle);
    checkCompilationGL(vertShaderHandle);

    fragShaderHandle = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    const char* fragS = fragSrc.c_str();
    glShaderSource(fragShaderHandle, 1, &fragS, 0);
    glCompileShader(fragShaderHandle);
    checkCompilationGL(fragShaderHandle);
}

void ShaderProgramGL::linkShader() {
    programHandle = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(programHandle, vertShaderHandle);
    glAttachShader(programHandle, fragShaderHandle);
    glBindAttribLocation(programHandle, 0, "vert_position");
    glLinkProgram(programHandle);
    checkLinkageGL();
    glValidateProgram(programHandle);
}
```

and

```
void ShaderProgramGL::bindGL() {
    glUseProgram(programHandle);
    glBindAttribLocation(programHandle, 0, "vert_position");
}

void ShaderProgramGL::unbindGL() {
    glUseProgram(0);
}
```

EDIT: Fixed not-releavant mistake
EDIT: Solved! Problem was a the display mapping (?) of the raspberry pi firmware: github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/142 Rendering was fine after all. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does `glError` say? Do the shaders compile and link properly?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you're drawing a single triangle with all 3 vertices being the same  `(-0.5, -0.5, 0.0)` and thus degenerating to an empty triangle (or a point, to be precise). So your drawing works perfectly, it just doesn't generate any fragments at all.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but that was just a mistake I made while trying to fix my problem.

Sadly still NOT working :(

Comment: @elfeck Ok, the rest looks good, though. Do you get any `glError` or do the shaders fail to compile/link? And I hope you didn't enable backface culling as you're currently drawing a clockwise triangle. By the way, that additional `glBindAttribLocation` after the `glUseProgram` is rubbish, since you've already bound the attrib to index 0 and rebinding doesn't effect until the next linking anyway (but that shouldn't cause any error, it's just useless).

Comment: No Errors whatsoever. But I just obseved very strange behavior:
With coords (-1, -1, 0, 1) (1, -1, 0, 1) (1, 1, 0, 1) I get a screen filled with my fragColor. Completely filled. If I change these values to the slightest nothing gets rendered. 
Transformations in the vert-Shader do nothing.

Comment: Solved! Problem was a the display mapping (?) of the raspberry pi firmware: https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/142

Rendering was fine after all. Thanks for your help!